# Type.GetTypeFromCLSID() returns not COM Wrapper

Tags: c#, com, .net-assembly, mscorlib

Trying to get `System.__Comobject` from `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(GUID)`, but instead it gives me right class, and also loads file assembly of him.

In other projects, this code correctly gets `System.__ComObject`, I don`t really know what forces it to load right assembly.

```cs
Guid clsid = Guid.Parse(guid);
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid);
```

Comment: I figured that left foot might start throbbing at your previous question.  You now have a [ComVisible] class that implements that CLSID.  So the CLR can now provide you with a recognizable instance.  Instead of the low-level `__ComObject` that represents the RCW for a coclass whose code lives in another module and probably written in a different language.  Whether that is wrong is not obvious, most programmers despise the RCW because the debugger gets gimpy.  But if that object was supposed to reside in that other module to operate correctly then it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The next line in App.config created this problem

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Still don`t know why this line can impact, i would to like to hear any explanation.

Comment: Your right foot is now in the danger zone as well.  This could only have an effect if your main program was written in a .NET language and uses a [ComVisible] class.  It controls the side-by-side instancing feature of the CLR, a feature that was designed to allow old COM components that were compiled to .NET 2 to still operate in a .NET 4 program.  You might have two copies of the CLR running in your process now.  Which does prevent one from recognizing the types and objects that were created in another.  This is not ideal.